# Overlapping boats in battleship game

Tags: javascript

I'm making a very simple battleship game of player 1 vs Computer in Javascript. I just cant figure out how to make the boats not overlap.
I calculate the coordinates like this for horizontal boats

```
row = Math.floor(Math.random() * boardSize)
col = Math.floor(Math.random() * (boardSize-ship_size+1))
```

and like this for vertical

```
row = Math.floor(Math.random() * (boardSize-ship_size+1));
col = Math.floor(Math.random() * boardSize);
```

and this is how I then place the boats (value 1 means that it is a part of a boat)

```
for(var i=0; i < ship_size; i++) {
  if (direction === 1) {
    board[row][col+i] = 1;
  } else {
    board[row+i][col] = 1;
  }
}
```

This works fine however they almost always overlap or lay next to each other. How can I make the boats not neighbour each other.

Comment: You're not doing any checks to see if there is already a boat on the board, when you create a new one.  You need to be checking the board co-ordinates with an `if` statement in a loop, to see if `board[x][y] == 1` anywhere